# Rational Normal Cone of degree d

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-geometry, affine-varieties, toric-geometry

Consider the surface in $\mathbb{C}^{d+1}$ parametrized by the map

$$\theta:\mathbb{C}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^{d+1}$$ 
defined by $(s,t)\rightarrow(s^d,s^{d-1}t,\dots,st^{d-1},t^d)$

And $J_d=\langle x_ix_{j+1}-x_{i+1}x_{j}:0\le i<j\le d-1\rangle\subseteq \mathbb{C}[x_0,\dots,x_d]$

Also we know $\widehat{C}_d=\theta(\mathbb{C}^2)$.
Then I want to show that $\theta(\mathbb{C}^2)=V(J_d)$.

One direction is clear. Let take $P_i\in \theta(\mathbb{C}^2)$ and suppose that $P_i=s^{d-i}t^i$ for all $i\in\{0,d\} \mbox{ and } s,t\in\mathbb{C}$. So it is clear that $P_i\in V(J_d).$

But i think the other direction is not easy.

We know that $V(J_d)=\left\{P\in\mathbb{C}^{d+1}:f(P)=0 \mbox{ for all } f \in J_d\right\}$. Let $P\in V(J_d)$. Suppose that $P=(P_0,\dots,P_d)\in\mathbb{C}^{d+1}$.
So we get $f(P)=P_iP_{j+1}-P_{i+1}P_j=0$ for all $f\in J_d$ and $0\le i< j\le d-1$.

Then it is clear that $P_iP_{j+1}=P_{i+1}P_j$.

Now, how can I show that $P\in \theta(\mathbb{C}^2)$? Because I cant see the transition between $\theta(\mathbb{C}^2)$ and point P.

I need to some idea for this direction.

Answer (score 3):

Because $P_0,P_1$ are complex numbers, there is $s,t\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $P_0=s^d$ and $P_1=s^{d-1}t$. Now use the recurence relations $P_iP_{j+1}=P_{i+1}P_j$ to get $P_k=t^ks^{d-k}$.

Comment: Firstly thank you so much for your comment. I know $P_0,P_1\in \mathbb{C}$ but why we can take $P_0=s^d$ and $P_1=s^{d-1}t$.  it is not clear to me...

Comment: Every complex has a $d-$th root.If $P_0=re^{\theta}$, then you could take $s=r^{1/d}e^{\theta/d}$. Now set $t=P_1/s^{d-1}$.